# Why wav from assets not playing on Android 4.3, but okay on 2.3 and 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My sound works okay on Emulator and on Android 2.3 and 4.2.
But why no sound on Android 4.3 -Huawei Mediapad Youth 7" tablet (with speakers!)?
Exception does not happen.
My code is below:

```
    try{
       AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("rec.wav");
       MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
       player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
       player.prepare();
       player.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
         myToast("Exception!!!");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: your table has no speakers ... but seriously, if you are catching and exception you can at least log it in logcat by simple `e.printStackTrace()` call ...

Comment: As Selvin said, log any `Exception` you're catching - never use an empty `catch` block.

Comment: Unfortunately logcat does not work since Android 4.1. But yes, it is possible to write log to file. But I suspect that people use another code for sound in Android 4.X

Comment: **"Unfortunately logcat does not work since Android 4.1."** : Yes it does. As long as you have debugging enabled on your device and also in your app you can read logcat using various ways (I use DDMS).

Comment: Just took a look at the exception. Exception does not happen!

Comment: @Niaz : Put a line of code in the `try` block after `player.start()` with a `Toast` saying something like "Player Started" and see what happens.

Comment: Solved! As I wrote below there was special sound setting for mediafiles in Android 4.3. My app works without any settings changes on other my devices. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! It was special settings for media sound level in my tablet, where sound  level was zero. But my thought was that sound buttons on the device manage all sounds. Sorry. But new Android versions really surprise me. I tryed my app on Android 2.2, 2,3, 4,2 without any settings.